# In PostgreSQL, can I add logic to check for conflicts and solve them when adding a constraint to an already populated table?

Tags: database, postgresql, constraints, liquibase, rollback

In my PostgreSQL geo_card_blocked_country table, there is such a constraint *geo_card_blocked_country_card_id_asserted_effective* :

```
EXCLUDE USING gist (card_id WITH =, country_a2 WITH =, geo_card_blocked_country_effective WITH &&)
```

Because our business logic doesn't require us to have this constraint anymore, I want to remove it. We are using liquibase, so I created this changeset:

```
    <changeSet id="foo" author="bar" runOnChange="true">
       <sql>
           ALTER TABLE public.geo_card_blocked_country
           DROP CONSTRAINT geo_card_blocked_country_card_id_asserted_effective;
       </sql>
    <rollback>
            <sql>
                ALTER TABLE public.geo_card_blocked_country
                ADD CONSTRAINT geo_card_blocked_country_card_id_asserted_effective
                EXCLUDE USING gist (card_id WITH =, country_a2 WITH =, geo_card_blocked_country_effective WITH &amp;&amp;);
            </sql>
        </rollback>
   </changeSet>
```

The changeset rolls nicely, but is not rollbackable after ex-noncompliant data have been inserted into the table :

```
ERROR: could not create exclusion constraint "geo_card_blocked_country_card_id_asserted_effective"
```

This is logic as we can now have two rows in the table with same card_id, country_code_a2 and overlapping geo_card_blocked_country_effective (daterange).

So my question is: can I replace geo_card_blocked_country_effective with NULL for all conflicting rows but one when running the rollback? For example, if two rows exist with card_id *221510* and country_code_a2 *'FR'*, update one's geo_card_blocked_country_effective to NULL so that the constraint doesn't fail and thus doesn't prevent the rollback.

Comment: It is `Postgres` or `Postgresql`. `psql` is the command line client to work with `Postgres`. Please revise the title and content.

Comment: The constraint you are adding looks to be the same as the one you are dropping. Is that a copy and paste error?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this is the point. We want to be able to rollback the changes every time we change the database. As you can see, it is between a <rollback> tag and the command should be run if we try to rollback the changes made in this changeset.

Comment: Alright I see now. 'update one's geo_card_blocked_country_effective to NULL' is a possibility assuming the column allows `NULL`s.  Two questions/issues I can think of is 1) Where you would do this in the migration process? 2) What `geo_card_blocked_country_effective WITH &&` would yield with a `NULL` value? I have used this sort of `gist` index , but honestly have not paid attention to its behavior with `NULL`.